# What are the $\pi^1$, $\pi^2$ and $\pi^3$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, isospin-symmetry

I found [this site](http://www.int.washington.edu/users/mjs5/Class_560/lec560_1/node8.html) to give a nice explanation of isospin. Apparently, the charged pions can be described by a superposition of $\pi^1$ and $\pi^2$.

> > Let us now consider the $\pi$'s in the context of isospin. There are three different charge states $\pi^+$, $\pi^0$ and $\pi^-$. They fit simply into a $I=1$ multiplet $\pi^a$, corresponding to  $I_Z=+1,0,-1$ respectively, with

$\pi^\pm = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\pi^1\mp i \pi^2)$
$\pi^0=\pi^3$

Where $\pi^\pm$, $\pi^0$ are field operators. However, I fail to understand, what the $\pi^1$, $\pi^2$ and $\pi^3$ are.

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without clicking on the link you provided. To make questions more accessible and guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), please include all relevant information, such as the explanation of notation or specific terminology used, in your question.

Comment: I did not find more information on that site, this is what spawned my question.

Comment: Forget the site.  Look up these definitions in s a basic particle physics book.

Comment: I've read Griffiths for example, but it never came up. Can you recommend one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at plain old vectors. Three dimensional space is spanned by ${\bf e}^1$, ${\bf e}^2$, and ${\bf e}^3$, also known as $\hat x$, $\hat y$, and $\hat z$. Of course:

$$ {\bf e}^i \cdot {\bf e}^j = \delta_{ij} $$

and

$$ ({\bf e}^i \times {\bf e}^j)\cdot {\bf e}^k = \epsilon_{ijk} $$

What are the eigenstate of rotations about the arbitrarily chosen $z$-axis? They are (normalized):

$$ {\bf e}^0 \equiv {\bf e}^3 $$

and

$$ {\bf e}^{\pm} = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}({\bf e}^1 \mp i{\bf e}^2)$$

You can show that the ${\bf e}^m$ with $m=(-1, 0, 1)$ are eigenvectors of a $z$-rotation by $\phi$ with eigenvalue:

$$ \lambda = \exp{(im\phi)}$$

This is known as the spherical representation of vectors, in contrast to the more familiar cartesian representation. (It's also called the fundamental representation of SO(3)). They transform exactly like a quantum spin-1 particle, aka, a vector boson.

Change the $\bf e$ to $\pi$, and replace spin with the name isospin, and you have 2 representations of pions.

The "cartesian" version isn't used, because the basis states aren't explicitly eigenstates of rotations about $I_3$--the equivalent $z$-axis in isospin space.

Comment: Nit: can you explain what you mean exactly by saying that $e^{1} \pm e^{2}$ are eigenvectors of rotations? As far as I can tell, it is demonstrably not the case.

Comment: So they are just the isospin components of the pion field? Then I just find the notation confusing, because for neutrinos, the numbers refer to the mass eigenstates. Is it $\pi^1 = I_1 \pi$?

Comment: Solenodon I think he is missing an $i$ there. The same applies for basic vectors of circular polarisation vectors.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus infinite zero is right. I completely forgot the $\sqrt{-1}$, which comes from $e^{i\phi}=cos{\phi}+i\sin{\phi}\propto  x +iy$.

Comment: Coming back to this, why do they need to be explicit eigenstates of rotations?